# Why does window height not adjust below height of tallest element on the page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay, I have a unique situation, first I am creating 10 `<li>`s using jQuery `append()`. Then I am adjusting the height of each `<li>` to be the window height / 10 so that as a whole they fill the whole screen height. My html contains nothing but `<div class="wrapper"></div>`. Here is my js:

```
// Create The Tree:

$('.wrapper').append('<ul>');
for (var x = 1; x <= 10; x++)
{
    $('.wrapper > ul').append('<li>Root Option ' + x + '</li>');
}

// Script The Tree:

var $winHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
console.log($winHeight);
var $liNumber = $('.wrapper > ul > li').size();
var $liHeight = $winHeight / $liNumber;
$('.wrapper > ul > li').css('height', $liHeight);

var $win = $(window)
$win.on('resize', update);
function update () {
    console.log(document.documentElement.clientHeight);
}
```

My problem is that if you view the console, you can see that it does not accuratly update the height of the window. When you resize the window, it wont log values lower than what it was when you last refreshed the page!

Comment: I am simply looking for a work-around that will give me the actual height of the users viewport in all situations.

Comment: Please, it would be best to create a concise example, post all the code required to reproduce the problem, and a jsFiddle demo.  What you're doing, by posting a live link and constantly changing it, is very annoying and unfair to those only trying to help you.  It's also not constructive to future readers.  Also see http://sscce.org

Comment: As I said in the answer below: you have to have doctype defined. Place `<!doctype html>` at the beginning of your HTML file and it will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean this? http://jsfiddle.net/reKSm/2/

```
var n = 20

$(document).ready(function (){
    $('.wrapper').append('<ul>');
    for (var x = 1; x <= n; x++)
        $('.wrapper > ul').append('<li>Root Option ' + x + '</li>');
    
    update_size();
    
    $(window).resize(function(){
    update_size();
    }); 
});

function update_size(){
    // Script The Tree:
    var $winHeight = $(window).height();
    var $liNumber = $('.wrapper > ul > li').length;
    var $liHeight = $winHeight / n;
    $('.wrapper > ul > li').css('height', $liHeight + 'px');    
};
```

Also, **you have to have *doctype* defined**.
Place `<!doctype html>` at the beginning of your html file and it will work.

And also don't place the upper JS code into another $(document).ready() function. At already has one in it :)

Comment: Sadly, you have the same problem as everyone else, it works in jsFiddle, but not on my server. You can check it out with the link at the top of the page, I updated my page with your script!

Comment: @watson, JavaScript works client-side - the fact that it's on a different server shouldn't matter. If it works in jsFiddle, or on any computer anywhere, the code works (cross-browser issues aside).

Comment: Im a dick, sorry, you are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any PX in your code, so I guess:

```
var $liNumber = $('.wrapper > ul > li').length;  // jquery.size() is deprecated (1.8)
var $liHeight = $winHeight / $liNumber;
$('.wrapper > ul > li').css('height', $liHeight + 'px');
```

---

In order to update on window resize, you must call the update function... on resize and actually have this function do something instead of a console.log():

```
var n = 20

$(document).ready(function (){
    // Update when window resized
    $(window).on('resize', update);
    // Add <ul> & <li>
    $('.wrapper').append('<ul>');
    for (var x = 1; x <= n; x++)
        $('.wrapper > ul').append('<li>Root Option ' + x + '</li>');
    // Update once
    update();
});

function update () {
    var $winHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
    var $liNumber = $('.wrapper > ul > li').length;
    var $liHeight = $winHeight / n;
    $('.wrapper > ul > li').css('height', $liHeight + 'px');
}
```

Preview in jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/reKSm/1/

Comment: thanks for the tips, but it doesn't solve my problem, i will update my site to include 'px'.

Comment: This works in jsFiddle, but not on my live site, which you can check out by changing the script src to stscript3.js! I have multiple versions of peoples attempts up right now, sorry for the inconvenience!

Comment: @watson, If it works in a jsFiddle, then it works.  Please don't run everyone in circles by constantly changing the code of your live demo.

Comment: the append() in js affects the height of the window object regularly and and does not in an iframe in jsfiddle!

Comment: I'm a dick, sorry, you are awesome!

Answer (score 1):

I made some revisions to your formatting and structure, but I believe this meets all of your needs. http://jsfiddle.net/ZBwa2/

```
//Default, global values.
var numLi = 10;

$(document).ready(function(){

  // Create The Tree:
    $('.wrapper').append('<ul />');        
    for (var x = 1; x <= numLi; x++) {
        $('.wrapper > ul').append('<li class="option">Root Option ' + x + '</li>');
    }

  // Call the update function on doument ready and window resize
    update();
    $(window).on('resize', update);
});

function update () {
    var $winHeight = document.documentElement.clientHeight,
        $liHeight = $winHeight / numLi;

    $('.wrapper .option').css('height', $liHeight);

    console.log(": Window Resized :");
    console.log("Window Height = "+$winHeight);
    console.log("Li Height = "+$liHeight);
}
```

Comment: I have updated my site with your changes and it still does not work. But Thanks!

Comment: Looks like you have 2 `$(document).ready..` declarations. Remove the outside one and you should be set! That is to say, `function update()` and `var numLi` should not be inside `$(document).ready(function(){ .. })`